# Move files to folder by date in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

Presently I have a 7ZIP command batch file that ZIPS files in a subdirectory by todays date and create a zip file with that date.

`"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a x:\Logs\HS\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_HS.zip X:\Logs\HS\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%* -xr!*.zip`

this is done for everyday of the month

```
c:\20121018\20121018.zip
c:\20121019\20121019.zip
```

Basically what I have also have in that same directory structure is a MONTH Folder. 201210. Basically what I require is a task which will move the zip file with today's date to its corresponding month folder. This would be for every month going forward.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Robocopy might be able to do it. It's included with Vista onwards and available for XP.

Comment: what you've tried? what problem you had?

Answer (score 1):

basically you just need to

1. for each file, extract from its name the month and year part
2. create the month directory if it does not exist
3. move the zip into the month directory

try this code to get you started...

```
for %%a in (*.zip) do (
  set fn=%%a
  set year=!fn:~0,4!
  set month=!fn:~4,2!
  if not exist !year!!month!\nul echo md !year!!month!
  echo move "%%a" "!year!!month!\%%a"
)
```

test it, remove the echo commands, test it again...

Comment: I removed the echo and it did not work as intended. It actually created a folder "!year!!month!" in that same DAY directory and moved the file into there (X:\LOGS\HS\20121019\!year!!month!) rather than moving up one directory and moving it in the month folder

Comment: why did you remove the echo *before* testing it? the code is just a sample, you need to prepare a little.. and enable delayed expansion